# Can't set my react project so that its width and height are the full size of the content

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I have a react project that renders different components depending on its route. I have my main css defined as:

```
html, body, #root, #root>div {
  height: 100% !important;
    width:100% !important;
}
```

My app's height and width is working when its first rendered ( component). However, when a different component renders (), the App's height and width will not change/update to the maximum of the browser's height and width.

In the below screenshot, as you can see in my google develop tool, the root HTML's width and height are not even the full browser page size. when this  component is rendered.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoHU8.png (Can't post image due to low reputation!, pls see the link instead!)

Any help will be much appreciated!

Below is the index.html used in my react app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/diamond.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://video-react.github.io/assets/video-react.css" />
    <meta
      charset="utf-8"
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/video-react.css" />
    <title>REACT APP</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And below is the App.js code and how I handled my routes:

```
// /client/App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
// import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
import SummonerNew from './SummonerNew';
import Search from './Search';
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import Home from './Home';
// import ChampionControl from './ChampionControl';
import ChampionControlGG from './ChampionControlGG';
import Footer from './Footer';
import FreeRotation from './FreeRotation';
// import styles from './styles.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    const { region , search } = this.props
    const App = ()=>(
      <div id="main-inner-wrap">
        <NavBar />
        <Search />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
          <Route exact path='/home' component={Home}/>
          <Route path='/champions' component={ChampionControlGG}/>
          <Route path='/profile/:region/:id' component={SummonerNew}/>
          <Route path='/rotation' component={FreeRotation}/>
          <Route component={Home} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    )
    return(
      <Switch>
        <App/>
      </Switch>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
  return {
    region:state.menu.region,
    search:state.menu.search
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(App));
```

Comment: can you provide more code ? thanks

Comment: @DanielVafidis I added the index.html code, let me know if you want to see other parts. Thanks

Comment: how did you handle routes? with react-router switch ? it's difficult to imagine the problem without code so I dont' really know where to start thinking about the eventual problem

Comment: @DanielVafidis Updated, add App.js and how I handled my routes